# An add-on to rate Matrix rows

Tags: matrix

I was thinking of using EE for a restaurant review kind of website. Ideally, I would like to create the restaurants as entries and have the entire menu of each restaurant as a Martix in their entry.

Next, I would like website members/visitors to rate individual dishes of a restaurant through star ratings (and possibly comment). There are quite a few ratings add-ons but they rate entries not rows in Matrix. Keep in mind that this should be done on the front-end and not CP.

Any ideas if there is anything that could help me? Or possibly look at the above from a different prospect to get it to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

The way you describe your project there is a pretty strong case for defining your dishes as Matrix rows instead of entries as you described (ie, restaurants defined as an entry with a Matrix for the menu and each dish being a Matrix row).

That said, as an alternative you *could* define dishes as fully-fledged entries and relate them to restaurants using a Playa field in the restaurant entry. This would allow you to use one of the rating add-ons that works with entries, but your menus would be more fragmented in the system and maybe less convenient/intuitive from a maintenance standpoint.

**But since ratable Matrix rows sounds like the best approach, take a look at [VZ Average](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-average)**. I have not tried it but according to the docs it supports rating Matrix rows.

> VZ Average is a flexible and minimal framework for rating or tallying
>   anything in EE that you can identify with an ID: a channel entry, a
>   comment, a Matrix row, or anything else. A few possible uses for it
>   include: star ratings, thumbs up/down ratings, flagging comments as
>   offensive, voting on entries, etc.

I actually discovered this add-on just now and wish I had known about it earlier since I had a very similar project requirement and ended up building a custom module. Building the module was fun, but if I had known about VZ Average I would have at least tested it out!

Comment: I'm the developer of VZ Average. It should be able to do exactly what you want (assuming I'm understanding you correctly). It will take a bit more work on your part than some of the drop-in entry ratings plugins you've seen, but it's also a lot more flexible. Take a look at the docs on GitHub and feel free to email me if you get stuck.

Comment: I had looked at VZ Average and installed it but for some reason, it doesn't give me as a custom field in Matrix. I can see it as a custom field on its own but when adding a new column to Matrix, it doesn't come up in the drop-down.

Comment: Hmm- I am not seeing the ability to add VZ as a Custom Field at all now- not in Matrix, not as a standard custom field. Weird. It is definitely installed and shows up in the list of Add-On->Custom Fields

Comment: Well, it is not a fieldtype it is a _module_. So you won't add it to custom field groups or as a matrix column. You use the module's template tags in your templates to _save_ or _display_ ratings associated with particular content. See the [documentation.](https://github.com/elivz/vz_average.ee_addon)

Comment: Yes, Alex is exactly right. You will do everything in the templates. Just make sure to set entry_type="matrix" and entry_id="{row_id}" in your module tags, so the ratings are attached to the Matrix row rather than the entry.